# PHP Sdk Facebook Upload Photos Approved

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api

ello,

I am trying to upload photos to an album I created and have the photos automatically approved. However when I do this, this still requires the user to manually login and approve all photos.

Is there a way I can make them approve automatically?

I have offline_access, user_photos, and read_stream extended permissions.

Comment: approved?! Am I missing something here?!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you should be fine if you had the publish_stream permission too.